# Best way to detect creation & recreation of HTML element?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that would add a sibling to a certain HTML element — let's call it X — on a certain webpage (unfortunately you must be a privileged user to access that webpage, so I can't give a link).

Element X is created when the webpage first loads and then recreated, as part of a whole subtree rooted at one of its predecessors — let's call that predecessor Y — on certain circumstances.

I've been able to use Mutation Observers to detect the recreation of X via detecting changes in Y's child nodes.

But that's quite complicated, and possibly not very efficient, as element Y goes through many changes.

Is there a way to directly observe the creation and recreation of element X? It has a unique id, so there's no problem identifying it.

I'm open to using tools other than Mutation Observers, if there are better ways.

Thank you!

Comment: `let doesXExist = document.getElementById(theIdOfX); new MutationObserver(() => { if(document.getElementById(theIdOfX)){ doesXExist = true; /* X exists */ } else { doesXExist = false; /* X does not exist */ } }, { childList: true, subtree: true }).observe(theY);` seems to be the most efficient. The check runs multiple times, for every little mutation, but the DOM is updated for each mutation anyway and `document.getElementById(theIdOfX)` is a constant-time lookup. Not sure if and how this needs to be adapted to the Web Extension API. Alternatively, Custom Elements have life-cycle callbacks.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a good reason why there's no similar API for the birth of a new node? I'm imagining something like Birth Observer, that would allow you to directly detect the addition of a new node instead of going through changes in the children of some predecessor and so on.